# Set a navigation bar for a list

Tags: css, html

I am generating a list with a lot of items inside it using the following code.

```
<ul class="custom-list">
                        <li class="item" *ngFor="let follower of followers">
                            <comment [username]=follower.from.username   [comment]=follower.text [imageURI]=follower.from.profile_picture></comment>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

The problem is, I do not want to extend the whole page because of number of `<li>` tags. Instead, I nead to keep the whole height of list as `height=500px;`and instead i need to have a slider in my list.
So how can i do this?

I have tried this:

```
style="height:500px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;"
```

but it disappears my `<li>` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.item_list
{
height:100px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto
}
```

```html
<ul class="item_list">
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
    <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
    <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
  <li class="item" >vivek</li>
</ul>
```

You can try this css

Answer (score 0):

Do you something like this? Simply `overflow-y:scroll;` (Open snippet in full page to see it correctly)

```css
.custom-list{
  height:500px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<ul class="custom-list">
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
  <li class="item" >Test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code

**HTML**

```
<ul class="custom-list">
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
  <li>Username</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-list {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: block;
}
```